# Node.JS Express.JS передача CORS методов PUT, DELETE и других

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, браузер, cors

Доброго, коллеги!

В принципе, не так часто работаю с Node, чисто для себя в основном.

И тут столкнулся с такой незадачей, что сервер не отдаёт ответы на не стандартные запросы аля PUT и DELETE.

Это касается больше браузеров, с другими системами пока проблем не обнаружил.

Headers стоят, всё (допустим) разрешают, но толку от этого - нуль-нуля.

Каково бы было ваше решение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замечу, что я не упомянул одну интересную вещь..

Хоть у меня и стоят все нужные Headers:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "DELETE, PUT, UPDATE, HEAD, OPTIONS, GET, POST");
  next();
});
```

Но, есть у меня такая штука, заглушка, в роутерах, которая всё равно ничего не пропустит:

```
app.all('*', function (req, res) {
    res.status(404).json({ response: 'error', code: 404, error: 'Не найден объект или метод!' });
  });
```

Соответственно, запрос от браузера сначала идет на метод OPTIONS (браузеру запрещено без спроса использовать не стандартные CORS), а такого у меня нет.

Всё что не указано - летит в 404!

Пока, чтобы не углубляться в дебри, я сделал так в роутере:

```
app.options('*', function(req,res,next){ res.sendStatus(200); });
```

Comment: Да все вы правильно сделали, зачем извиняетесь-то? *Ответ, кстати, вы очень зря пометили общим - репутацию вы так не заработаете.*

Comment: @pavelm Ну, я здесь не для репутации))

Comment: но лишней она не будет :-)

Comment: @pavelmayorov но спасибо, учту))

Comment: @PavelMayorov, но вообще-то всем всё разрешать - не очень подход ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy это нормальный подход если API не полагается на куки и сессию, а использует токены. Еще этот подход применим при запуске в локальном окружении.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ну да, но это ж нигде не сказано ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, это API с токенами)) В принципе, можно ещё дополнительный разбор app.options сделать.. Но особого смысла в этом не вижу.